# Turtle Clear Screen

Tags: python, python-turtle

I'm not sure how to get rid of the black arrow, if you could help that would be great! Thanks, also if you have any other modifications to make the game better that would be awesome as well! Thanks again!

It says I need to write more detail, so I m just going to keep typing fora bit and hope that I have enough words to write. It should be good right around here.

````
import math
import random

score = 0
print ("\n" * 40)
print("Welcome Player, I Hope You Have What it Takes to be the Next WARLORD BOSS")
print("Enemies Killed:\n0")

#Title
t=turtle.Pen()
t.pencolor("magenta")
t.hideturtle()
t.penup()
t.setposition(-300,350)
t.write("Catch 40 turtles for a suprise  ( ͡° ͜ʖ ͡°)", font=("Verdana", 18))

#Tip
text=turtle.Pen()
t.pencolor("magenta")
t.hideturtle()
turtle.clear()
t.penup()
t.setposition(-100, -350)
t.write("TOUCH THE EDGES, I DARE YOU", font=("Verdana", 18))```



#Set up screen
wn = turtle.Screen()
wn.bgcolor("dim gray")
wn.title("EXEXEXEXEEXXEXEXE HACK COMMENCING␀␀␀␀␀")

#Draw border
mypen = turtle.Turtle()
mypen.penup()
mypen.speed(10)
mypen.hideturtle()
mypen.setposition(-300,-300)
mypen.pendown()
mypen.pensize(3)
for side in range(4):
    mypen.color("crimson")
    mypen.forward(300)
    mypen.color("gold")
    mypen.forward(300)
    mypen.left(90)
mypen.hideturtle()


#Create player turtle
player = turtle.Turtle()
player.color("powder blue")
player.shape("arrow")
player.penup()
player.speed(0)

#Create goal
goal = turtle.Turtle()
goal.color("red")
goal.shape("turtle")
goal.penup()
goal.speed(0)
goal.setposition(-100, -100)

#Set speed
speed = 1

#Define functions

def turnleft():
    player.left(30)

def turnright():
    player.right(30)

def increasespeed():
    global speed
    speed +=0.5

def decreasespeed():
    global speed
    speed -= 1

#Set keyboard binding
turtle.listen()
turtle.onkey(turnleft, "Left")
turtle.onkey(turnright, "Right")
turtle.onkey(increasespeed, "Up")
turtle.onkey(decreasespeed, "Down")



while True:
    player.forward(speed)

    #Boundary check
    if player.xcor() > 300 or player.xcor() < -300:
        print("I Knew you could never be a WARLORD... Try Again")
        quit()

    if player.ycor() > 300 or player.ycor() < -300:
        print("I Knew you could never be a WARLORD... Try Again")
        quit()

    #Collision checking
    d= math.sqrt(math.pow(player.xcor()-goal.xcor(),2) + math.pow(player.ycor()-goal.ycor(),2))
    if d < 20 :
        goal.setposition(random.randint(-300,300), random.randint(-300, 300))
        score = score + 1
        print ("\n" * 40)
        print("Wow, You Actually got one!")
        print("I think you Might Have What it Takes to be the Next WARLORD BOSS")
        print("Enemies Killed")
        print (score)
````

Comment: SO community is here to help you, but no one got plenty of time to debug your whole code, so please be specific and describe on which line what scenario is causing issue. Usually it's ideal to give a minimal example code which is easy to understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code is your problem:

```
text=turtle.Pen()
t.pencolor("magenta")
t.hideturtle()
turtle.clear()
t.penup()
t.setposition(-100, -350)
t.write("TOUCH THE EDGES, I DARE YOU", font=("Verdana", 18))
```

You copied and pasted but forgot to update `t.` to instead be `text.`  Also, `turtle.clear()` doesn't make sense as that refers to a different turtle altogether:

```
text = turtle.Pen()
text.hideturtle()
text.pencolor("magenta")
text.penup()
text.setposition(-100, -350)
text.write("TOUCH THE EDGES, I DARE YOU", font=("Verdana", 18))
```